# Extract field using the ‘cut’ command and piping to find the highest value in the extracted field to a separate file

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

How can I extract a field #3 (salaries) from a file (employees) using the ‘cut’ command and then use the piping to create a new file (highest) that will contain the highest value in the extracted field #3 (salaries)?

What I've tried so far:

> $ cat employees | cut -f 3 | sort -nr

Output:
[image]
It did extract field 3 for me and it sorted the values in the field #3. But what can I add so that I can extract the highest value from the sorted field #3 into a seperate file called highest?

FYI -> I used the display function just so I can check what I was doing

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: How about `man head`.

Comment: Okay, i have edited my question now.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat employees | cut -f 3 | sort -nr | head -1  >> highest
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can ask `sort` to sort according to a certain field, instead of:

```
cut -f 3 | sort -nr
```

You can do:

```
sort -k 3 -nr
```

From that, you can still decide what to do (e.g. if you're only interested in the highest one, just do a `head -n 1`, you can do a `head -1` but this seems to be unadvised).